# passing properties to msiexec

Tags: windows-installer

Let's imagine I've passed properties with their values to msiexec that aren't defined anywhere in my msi package. Do those properties get created, or are they ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they get created. Once you pass a property via msiexec command line, you can address them as if you define them directly in Property table. Windows Installer gurus might point out differences (if there are), but in terms of usage I didn't notice any.

Comment: To be sure that the properties can be accessed in the MSI itself you should really define them in the SecureCustomAction property. This is a list of PUBLIC (uppercase) properties that are allowed to pass its value from the client (GUI) to the server (actual installation) process in secure environments with locked down user accounts running the install.